# Tar directories while sending with SSH

Tags: ssh, backup, rsync

Nowadays, when I want to backup my server, I log in to it and then I execute the command below which tars the local directory "/ebs1" and sends it to another server at IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and saves it at that backup server with the name "/ebs1_2019-06-02.tar".

```
tar -cvf - "/ebs1" | ssh -p 22 root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "cat > /ebs1_2019-06-02.tar"
```

It works just fine. But did you notice that I am logged in the server that is being backuped to run the command above? But what if I want to be logged in the backup server, how do I change the command above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way:

```
ssh root@the.client.to.be.backed.up tar cf - /ebs1 >/ebs1_2019-06-02.tar
```

This doesn't work well if the directory to be backed up contains space or any special characters, in which case you need to use a command like this:

```
ssh root@the.client.to.be.backed.up tar cf - "'/directory name'" >/ebs1_2019-06-02.tar
```

...and this can become inconvenient real quick. You might want to write a script on the target computer containing the `tar` command, and run that via `ssh`, so you don't need to escape everything in the command line.

If the directory name doesn't contain any special characters, however, the first command should do.

Comment: why not use netcat (nc)

Comment: Because the question was "how to change the command [in the post]". You could of course use netcat, or a real backup solution for that matter.

Comment: Your command looks to work but I cant make it work! I asks me to login to my server and then it says "tar: Removing leading `/' from member names" and nothing happens. The directory that I want to tar is pretty huge, but WHEN I executed the command I originally posted (#1) the tar is being sent while it's being generated! But your command takes too long... maybe it's generating the TAR file and will only send the TAR file when it's fully generated? If so, I am pretty sure there will be no space left on my server to save the tar, it really needs to be sent while is being generated!

Comment: It should send the data through the network, so the file on your side should grow periodically, at least it did on my system (Debian 9). Add the `v` switch to the command to see what it does. Also, you might want to consider using a more robust backup solution.